# Input string was not in correct format3

Tags: c#, asp.net

Line 50:

```
total_cost += Convert.ToInt16(lbl_total_price.Text);
```

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.   Exception Details:
>   System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

how to correct this?

Comment: And what is the total price in the input box?

Comment: By providing a valid value in `lbl_total_price.Text` or using `int16.TryParse`

Comment: The `string` could be too large/too small, or having `$` symbol, or having decimal separator, or having non-numerical characters, or wrong thousand separator according to your current culture... but in all cases, please check the `lbl_total_price.Text`

Comment: Note that `Convert.ToInt16(string)` will use the current thread culture which may (or may not) be what you are expecting. It's better to always specify the culture to be used, or use the invariant culture if the number has a fixed format.

Comment: Not a single one of the 1260+ "input string was not in a correct format [c#]"  questions on the site could have helped you here?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if *price* (which can be, say, `14.95`) is an *integer* value (`Int16` in the question); probably you mean `Double` or `Decimal`:

```
  // Or .ToDecimal which is a better choice for money
  total_cost += Convert.ToDouble(lbl_total_price.Text);
```

A better approach is *try parse*:

```
  Double value; // Or Decimal

  if (Double.TryParse(lbl_total_price.Text, out value))
    total_cost += value;
  else {
    // lbl_total_price.Text is not a floating point value, say, "bla-bla-bla"
    //TODO: put required response for such format error
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if value is numeric using int.TryParse

```
int total_cost;
bool isInt = int.TryParse(lbl_total_price.Text,  out total_cost );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of things that could be going wrong here, but the basic gist is that the value that is in your `lbl_total_price` textbox isn't a valid integer (thus the conversion is failing).

You may want to consider using the [`Int16.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hh1awhy(v=vs.110).aspx) method that will return a boolean to indicate if the parse was successful or not :

```
int price;
if(Int16.TryParse(lbl_total_price.Text, out price))
{
     // If your conversion was successful, then price will be stored here
}
else
{
     // Uh oh. It wasn't in the proper format.
}
```

However without knowing more about the format that your value is in, it could be difficult to tell exactly what is wrong. If you have any non-numeric values, you might consider explicitly stripping them off prior to parsing your value as seen below via a [`Regex.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) call:

```
// Remove all non-numeric data via a Regular Expression
var cleanedPrice = Regex.Replace(lbl_total_price.Text,@"[^\d]","");
total_cost += Convert.ToInt16(cleanedPrice);
```

Finally, if you are working with a price and actually have non-integer data like decimal places, you might consider simply parsing the value as a `Decimal` or `double` :

```
total_cost += Convert.ToDecimal(cleanedPrice);
```

or

```
total_cost += Convert.ToDouble(cleanedPrice);
```